# php updating database through dynamically generated form

Tags: php, database

I'm creating an inventory system for the company I work for, and everything's been running along smoothly until I got to the part where I build a form to update the number of sheets in the database. It's giving me an undefined index error on this line.

```
$newSheetNum = $_POST['change_stock'];
```

I have made an alert and I know that it's oulling the paper_id, and change_stock values, but it still won't process. Here's the php code that builds the box.

```
$paperID = $row['paper_id'];
$sheetsIn = $row['number_sheets'];
echo "<form id='paper$paperID' name=form$paperID method='POST' action='paperUpdated.php'>";
echo "<div class='paperBlock alignTextCenter'>";
echo "<p style='display:none;'>";
echo $row['company']." ";       
echo "<strong> Paper ID:</strong><input name='paperID' value='$paperID'>".$paperID."</input></p>";
echo "<p>" .$row['paper_weight']." ".$row['sheet_size']." ".$row['paper_mill']." ".$row['paper_finish']." " .$row['paper_color']. " ".$row['stock_type']."</p>";
echo "<div class='inStock' style='text-align:center;display:block;'>";
echo "<p>Sheets in stock: <strong class='sheetStock'>".$row['number_sheets']."</strong></p></div>";
echo "<div class='stockEntry'>";
echo "<input name='change_stock' class='changeStock' value='$sheetsIn'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Done' style='width:70px;height:23px;' autofocus />";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</form>";
```

Here is some more of the updated.php file:

```
//Gets values from paperID and changeStock fields
$paperID = $_POST['paperID'];
$newSheetNum = $_POST['change_stock'];

echo "<script>alert('Paper ID: ' + '$paperID' + ' Sheets Entered: ' + '$newSheetNum');</script>";

$query = "UPDATE `paper_availability` SET `number_sheets` = '$newSheetNum' WHERE `paper_availability`.`paper_id` = '$paperID';";

//Executes the SQL query.  If successful the records are returned to $result
$result = mysql_query($query)or die("SQL Error " . mysql_error() . "<script>alert ('SQL String: $sql')</script>" );
```

Any help would be appreciated. They're counting on me having this up and running very soon, and I've hit a roadblock here. TY in advance.

UPDATE: I discovered that the new information IS updating the database, but my updated.php file has some coding in it that's halting the DOM rendering the rest of the page.

Comment: did you know, you don't need one echo per line

Comment: I was always taught that way. But I guess it does add a little extra work.

Comment: your definition of the paperID input field is wrong.. replace `<input name='paperID' value='$paperID'>".$paperID."</input>` with `<input name='paperID' value='$paperID' />`

Comment: I changed to the code you suggested, but I'm still getting the error. Added note: The error isn't actually writing out on the screen I have to go to the source to see it. Which seems odd to me. Never had that happen before.

Comment: After reviewing the code from my browser after the php processes it, the values are dropped. How can Javascript pick up the values on the new page, then have php drop them?

Comment: Have you checked that the values are present before submitting the form? (*viewing source*)

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding a php header to the top that redirects back to the paperUpdate.php after it processes paperUpdated.php and it shows the change. The page loads so fast that it makes it look like it was just an Ajax call. Still very odd that I couldn't get a confirmation page to spit out the info that was entered.